# Stuck with rails g model User provider uid name oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-login

I have already a User model (https://github.com/frankzk/pinteresting2) and now to make add the option of facebook login this tutorial (https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw) tells me that i need to run

```
rails g model User provider uid name oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime
```

I know that i cant do that, because i already have a user model.

Whats should i don in this case?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

```
rails g migration AddFacebookFieldsToUser
```

In the created file you can do

```
add_column :users, :facebook_id, :string
```

Where `:users` is the table name and `:facebook_id` is the name of the column and `:string` is the type of the column.

After you have finished changing the file you can then run `rake db:migrate` which will make the db changes.

To allow reverting migrations you can use `up/down` such as this:

```
def up
  add_column :users, :facebook_id, :string
end

def down
  remove_column :users, :facebook_id
end
```